# Question regarding vector direction and Unit Circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, conventions

> Find the electric field at the origin for a line of charge density λ on the $y > 0$ portion of the unit circle if λ is constant.

The solution provided was:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\lambda d \phi}{4\pi e_0}(-\hat\rho).$$
If it is $y>0$, why is the direction ($-\hat\rho$) negative?

Comment: What is $\hat\rho$ ?

Comment: I guess it is the radial unit vector in polar coordinate system?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the electric field points from positive to negative, so if $\lambda > 0$, the electric field points away from the line, towards the origin (negative radial direction). Then the integral is just summing up these contributions. Also, the value of $\hat{\rho}$ depends implicitly on $\phi$, as the radial direction changes as you move on the semi-circle.

Comment: is p_hat = cos(phi)x_hat + sin(phi)y_hat?

Comment: Yes, it's the unit vector pointing radially outward at $\phi$. $\hat{\rho} = \hat{x} \cos \phi + \hat{y} \sin \phi$